# Помогите с тегом audio

Tags: javascript, reactjs, аудио

Почему когда подставляю ссылку на прямую, то могу подключиться к аудиопотоку, когда ставлю переменную в source, то не могу подключиться к аудипотоку?

так работает

```
<audio className="stream" volume={this.props.volume} controls ref={this.stream}>
    <source src="https://link" type="audio/mpeg"/>
</audio>
```

так не работает

```
<audio className="stream" volume={this.props.volume} controls ref={this.stream}>
    <source src={this.props.streamLink} type="audio/mpeg"/>
</audio>
```

Comment: Посмотрите, что в пропсах приходит. Тем же console.log(this.props.streamLink)

Comment: @xydope приходит нужная ссылка

Comment: код компонента и родителя прикрепите